# Google Drive: Download of shared folders for signed out users

Tags: download, google-drive-api, shortcut

I want to share Google Drive folders by sharing their folder link to people. An example folder is [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17Jh-Va8M1XQSJyrugV-iAtOTIwYePbvV](http://An%20example%20folder%20is%20https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17Jh-Va8M1XQSJyrugV-iAtOTIwYePbvV)

The folder contains original files as well as the new Google drive "shortcuts" (btw: I'm the owner of the original files where those shortcuts link to).
I want that also people which **aren't signed in to a Google account** are able to download the whole folder. I noticed 2 new problems which occured since Google introduced the new shortcut system this year:

1. signed out users aren't able to **download all files of a folder** with one click. There's no "Download All" button any more. It's just possible to download single files.
2. Signed out useres aren't able to download **Shortcut-files**. Just original files by clicking onto "Download"

Do you have an idea how to fix problems 1) and 2) for signed out users?

Answer (score 0):

### As a workaround for 1):

- Create a folder inside of the main shared folder and mive all files to the nested folder.
- When the user opens the main folder he can download with one click the nested folder and all contained files:

[image]

As for 2)

- The shortcuts are no files but just links to files - if the original files are not shared with the permission `Anyone on the internet with this link can view` - then users who are not signed in cannot access those files.
- You need to share the original files accordingly, in this case the user will be able to open the shortcut and then go on `File->Download`.
- Arguably it makes more sense to directly move the original file into the shared folder instead of using shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for your help. To clarify my problem I added a link to a shared folder in my 1st post.
1) Since I'm using a lot of different folders, it's no option for me to put them inside multiple nested folders just as a workaround for this problem.

2): I've set the permission of the original files to "Anyone on the internet with this link can view", but still there aren't able to be downloaded for signed out users.
Since I'm using a complex system of different folders a file has to be part of multiple folders. One folder contains the original files but for the others I've to create shortcuts.

Comment: What is wrong with creating an additional folder and move or your files there? Unfortunately I do not think there is another way. The restrictions are as they are because Google wants them to be this way.